# Namespace error python zeep

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, soap-client, zeep

I'm trying to read this Soap API http://telemetriaws1.ana.gov.br/ServiceANA.asmx?WSDL. 
When I try to call `DadosHidrometeorologicosGerais` function I getting this error:

```
File "/home/1234/.local/share/virtualenvs/data_getter-1W9NAele/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 570, in _get_component
return items[qname]
KeyError: <lxml.etree.QName object at 0x7f2e93fa6d00>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
zeep.exceptions.LookupError: No element 'DocumentElement' in namespace None. Available elements are: NewDataSet
```

All other function working ok.

Here my code:

```
 from zeep import Client

 client = Client('http://telemetriaws1.ana.gov.br/ServiceANA.asmx?WSDL')
 client.service.DadosHidrometeorologicosGerais(codEstacao='86450500', dataInicio='05/05/2018', dataFim='05/05/2018')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the xml file seems generated from some data set. The "id" attribute does not match the identification of the element.

A possible solution would be to omit the zeep parsing of the XML and returning the [raw data](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/client.html#configuring-the-client). The use the module [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) to parse it.

```
from zeep import Client, Settings
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

settings = Settings(force_https=False, raw_response=True)
WSDL = 'http://telemetriaws1.ana.gov.br/ServiceANA.asmx?WSDL'

client = Client(WSDL, settings=settings)

response = client.service.DadosHidrometeorologicosGerais(codEstacao='86450500',
                                                     dataInicio='05/05/2018',
                                                     dataFim='05/05/2018')

root = ET.fromstring(response.content)
```